# bind value to textblock inside resourcedictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have following resourcedictionay.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:samplePrjkt"
                    >

    <ToolBar x:Key="MyToolbar" Height="120">
        <!--Template-->
        <GroupBox Header="Template" Style="{StaticResource ToolbarGroup}" Margin="3">
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,2,0,2">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextValue}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>
    </ToolBar>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

that resourcedictionay used in following WPF user-control like follows.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Sampleprjkt.sample.sampleWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sampleprjkt"            
       >
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="29*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="107*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource MyToolbar}"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I'm trying to bind value to this text block inside the WPF user-control constructor like follows

```
    public partial class SampleWindow : UserControl
    {

        private string _textValue;

        public string TextValue
        {
            get { return _textValue; }
            set
            {
                _textValue = value;

            }
        }

        public SampleWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _textValue = "XXXXX";


        }   

    }
```

but once I run this, I can see "XXXXX" value not set to `<TextBlock Text="{Binding TextValue}"></TextBlock>` , what I missed here ?

Comment: I suppose you can fix binding by adding relativeSource: `Text="{Binding TextValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=SampleWindow }}"`. but overall design is questionable

Comment: @ASh - I agree that the design is questionable - but aren't we further compounding the issue by adding a RelativeSource binding here? Is working under the assumption that the parent will always be a UserControl/SampleWindow to a control instance defined in an isolated ResourceDictionary recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ContentControl is missing a DataContext, which is null. The Binding will always refer to the object in the DataContext and thus the Binding will not find the TextValue.

You could simply set the DataContext of the UserControl to itself:

```
public SampleWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _textValue = "XXXXX";

    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

The DataContext is inherited down to the TextBlock, which will now display the text.

Answer (score 0):

The path of a binding that you define in XAML ("TextValue" in your case) refers to a name of the property of the current `DataContext` of the element (`TextBlock` in your case) or the source of the binding.

This means that you should either set the `DataContext` as suggested by @Sharada Gururaj:

```
public SampleWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _textValue = "XXXXX";
    DataContext = this;
}
```

...or specify an explicit source of the binding:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TextValue, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"></TextBlock>
```